# Could not load file or assembly WebGrease,dll Version Clash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, gac

This problems is nagging me from last night ,I can't figure out its solution.

[image]

Well let me explain the structure of my project,In a single solution file I have three projects two are asp.net mvc 4 projects and one in C# Library,the problem started when I added new asp.net mvc 4 project.

I have tried several solutions ,but they didn't worked for me,

1. nuget restore (first I deleted the whole package folder then applied
   nuget restore).
2. Tried uninstalling asp.net web optimization package then
   webgrease and then installed them both.
3. Tried cleaning temp folder of asp.net.
4. Removed xmlns from web.config assemblyBinding tag

### **Note:**

- By using the first solution I was able to fix the problem on my home dev machine,but the same solution doesn't works on my office dev machine :(
- I have also discussed this problem on [asp.net chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43899/asp-net) before posting question here.
- [Assembly binding log aka FusionLog Viewer](http://pastie.org/private/tje4hareqox5clnwmzebgw)
- tried several SO solutions.

### Update:

- Moved the two MVC4 webapp in seperate solutions,so one solution is
  working fine but another is having same webgrease problem.

### Solution:

- Check my answer below for the solution which worked in my situation.

Comment: Guys can anyone help me out on this,its still haunting me..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi guys,**

So I merged my both solutions,now both mvc4 projects along with a test case project and C# Class library project are in the same solution.

*I finally made it work for me,here are the steps with the nuget console commands*

1. uninstall-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization
2. uninstall-Package webgrease
3. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.0

### Note:

I was having WebGrease 1.5.2 and Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization 1.1.3 in my project and I had to rollback to earlier version to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If your solution it's for 64-bit and the dll-s are for 32 bit, go to:

1. IIS / Application Pools
2. Right click your website  app pool / advanced  settings
3. Set 'Enable 32-bit Applications' to TRUE

Comment: This is not the answer. There is no platform mismatch here. it is a VERSIONING conflict

Comment: @cristi its not even hosted,I'm using IIS Express provided within VS 2012

Comment: @Cristi although not directly related to this problem,but a good advice, +1 :)